# Extract href from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am given the following html :

```
<A HREF="Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_uid58167/"><IMG border="0" SRC="SOMETHING" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_uid58167/">Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_&gt;</A> Jun 12  2013        
<A HREF="Acetobacter_pasteurianus_386B_uid214433/"><IMG border="0" SRC="SOMETHING" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="Acetobacter_pasteurianus_386B_uid214433/">Acetobacter_pasteurianus_386B_u&gt;</A> Aug  8  2013
```

and many more...
I want to extract the href from here.

Here's my python script : (page_source contains the html)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)

links = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})

for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href',None)
    if link != None:
        print link
```

But this keeps returning the following error :

```
    links = soup.find_all('A',attrs={'HREF': re.compile("^http://")})
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using BeautifulSoup *version 3*, not version 4. `soup.find_all` is then not interpreted as a method, but as a *search for the first `<find_all>` element*. Because there is no such element, `soup.find_all` resolves to `None`.

Install [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead, the import is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

BeautifulSoup 3 is instead imported as `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`.

If you are sure you wanted to use BeautifulSoup 3 (**not** recommended), then use:

```
links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})
```

As a side note, because you limit your search to `<a>` tags with a certain value, *there will always be a `href` attribute on the elements that are found. Using `.get()` and testing for `None` is entirely redundant. The following is equivalent:

```
links = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})

for tag in links:
    link = tag['href']
    print link
```

BeautifulSoup 4 also supports [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), which could make your query a little more readable still, removing the need for you to specify a regular expression:

```
for tag in soup.select('a[href^=http://]'):
    link = tag['href']
    print link
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the split command?

Iterate over all lines of the file and d something like that:

```
href = line.split("HREF=\"")[1].split("\"")[0]
```

Comment: No, because HTML is rarely as simple and regular as all that. Using a HTML parser is the right way to go about it. Provided you use methods supported by the actual implementation.

Comment: That assumes all attributes and their values must be on the same line.